# How to get old image in edit VueJS ?

Tags: vue.js

I have form edit, i need change name, title but don't change image and keep old image. 
In template i have HTML code

```
             <div class="form-group">
              <label>Image</label>
              <input type="file"  v-on:change="onImageChange">
            </div>
```

But `input type="file"` can't use `v-model`, I have function use createImage in form create

```
  onImageChange(e) {
    let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (!files.length)
      return;
    this.createImage(files[0]);
  },
  createImage(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let vm = this;
    reader.onload = (e) => {
    vm.list.image = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  },
```

How can I edit to retain the old image name without having to re-add it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you want to get the image original name?Just follow:

```
<input type="file" @change="fileUploaded" />
<button @click="upload">Upload</button>
```

and the script:

```
  export default {
    data(){
     selectedFile: null
    },
    methods: {
      fileUploaded(event) {
        console.log(event.target.files[0].name) //here is the original name
        this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
      },
      upload() {
       let fd = new FormatData()
       fd.append('image', this.selectedFile, 'GiveItAnotherNameHere')
       axios.post('url', fd) //upload it to backend
      }
    }
  }
```

Though,there are many tutorials on vue.js upload image.I like [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-handle-file-uploads-in-vue-2) and recommend you to follow.Also they offer the source code and a demo to see.

Comment: Thanks, but i want retain the previous image, when i click Upload if no input, i get error 500 @@

Comment: yes,you have to add validation of course.If you want to upload a new image and want to keep the old one then store the old one into a property object

Comment: did you manage how to do this?... Can you help me?